# Write a bmp image from a c++ array

Tags: bitmap, bitmapimage

I have written a class to perform certain manipulations on a 3D grayscale image that I have placed in a vector container of doubles and use indexing to iterate through the rows, columns and slices.

I want to output this image as a bitmap file. I know I have to first write the header info but I've no clue how to go about it.

Comment: I am able to create a bmp image from the array now but I want a grayscale image, however the only compression method setting in the BMP header that seems to work for me is BI_RGB and that as the name suggests creates an RGB image. 


My data as I mentioned is an array of floats and I want each float value to be read as a grayscale value rather than an RGB value. How do I get a grayscale image?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fwrite()`. This function can write struct of data into file.

For example you define the header as a struct:

```
struct Header {
     int len;
     ...
}

struct Header header;
header.len = any_len;
hander. = ... ; // any other info of header

fwrite(&header, sizeof(header), 1, fp);
```

This way, you write header info into the file.

Then, if your bmp content is in an array of doubles:

```
double dots[N]; // this is your bmp point array
fwrite(dots, sizeof(double) * N, 1, fp);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer,but what struct of data? And that still doesn't tell me how to create a header.

Comment: Also does it matter that my array is an array of doubles, not bytes?

Comment: array of doubles are also bytes, right? I updated my answer again to show you how to write array to file.

Comment: @Lisa If you think my answer helped you, please up-vote and accept my answer. That will add reputation to me.